# UWP - app in background state and async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, win-universal-app, uwp

I created app for universal windows platform(for Windows 10 desktop). I use DispatcherTimer in app. Timer run async method. When app in foreground it is work.
But app is background(I minimize a window) async method not work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is not running in the foreground and tasks need to be executed, it is well known that we need to implement the [background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks) for the app.

**But**, background tasks in UWP are lightweight. Due to memory constraints, battery life issue, I'm not sure what you need can be done in background task of UWP.

That doesn't mean you can't use `DispatcherTimer` in the background task, but background tasks are limited to 30 seconds of wall-clock usage, and it can be terminated by system for example when it throw the out-of-memory exception. So, if you want to execute your task every one minute, then it will not work.

The `TimerTrigger` which is mentioned by @ibebbs has a minimal time intervals which is 15 minutes, so I'm also not sure this can be used in your scenario.

Problem is what you need to do in the background task and how often, you can leave a comment to tell that, so can we continue to discuss on this issue.

Comment: I need show notification. I need it once of several minutes.

Comment: @FetFrumos, there are 4 kinds of Notifications in UWP app: local, scheduled, periodic, and push. You can refer to [Choose a notification delivery method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-choosing-a-notification-delivery-method). For your scenario, you can try periodic notification, its recurrence interval can be delayed by up to 15 minutes. Or you can try push notification, push notification from your app server once of several minutes.

Comment: Thank you. I made simple. I change logic my app.

Answer (score 1):

You should [Create and register a background task that runs in a separate process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task) and use a [TimerTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.aspx) to invoke it at the desired interval.